# About prime ramification in cyclotomic fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I got a question about lemma 2.2, in the appendix of Cyclotomic Fields I+II written by Karl Rubin.
Let me explain its situation:

a. $m$ and $M$ are fixed positive integers(especially, $M$ is odd).

b. $F$ is the maximal real subfield of $\mathbb Q(\mu _m)$

c. $r$ is a positive squarefree integer divisible only by primes $l$ which
      split completely in $F/ \mathbb Q$ and $l \equiv 1 \pmod M$.

He says, "a simple ramification argument shows that  $\mu _M \cap F(\mu _r) =1$."
I am eager to understand this...If you explain this, I would appreciate about it.

Comment: I proved this, but it does NOT need any ramification arguments.